GARCH-MIDAS model for forecasting volatility?
I had a problem when I just estimated the GARCH-MIDAS model on Eviews: I found only the MIDAS model. Can I estimate the GARCH(1,1) model and MIDAS separately, and then multiply them to have GARCH-MIDAS? Or is there another way to estimate the model on Eviews?
